# Dynamically linq without columns

Tags: linq, dynamic

how can I get all Columns of a tabel via dynamic linq? Is there something like wildcards? For example:

```
var query = db.myTable.select("*").orderby("Name"); or
var query = db.myTable.select("new { * }").orderby("Name");
```

and how can I convert the query to a List?

```
ar query = db.myTable.select("new { * }").orderby("Name").toList();
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'all Columns' ? All the columns names, all the data from the table...

Comment: If you want to get all columns, do not use `select`: `var query = db.myTable.Orderby("Name")`. If it is going abouy `ToList`? have tried anythig? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: My table has about 30 fields like Id, Name, Address, Age, ... I am looking for an approach to work with something like wildcards '*' to not specify all field names. I only have to work with dynamic Linq.